# Importing a different wallet address in my wallet app

Tags: wallets, ethereum-wallet-dapp

I'm trying to create a basic crypto wallet and I want to add an import wallet functionality like other wallets but how can I do that ?
Is there any API which I can use for this ?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using web3.js, then you can add an existing account by using the `web3.eth.accounts.wallet.add(account);` function.

[Example](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.11/web3-eth-accounts.html#id31):

```
    web3.eth.accounts.wallet.add('0x4c0883a69102937d6231471b5dbb6204fe5129617082792ae468d01a3f362318');
> {
        index: 0,
        address: '0x2c7536E3605D9C16a7a3D7b1898e529396a65c23',
        privateKey: '0x4c0883a69102937d6231471b5dbb6204fe5129617082792ae468d01a3f362318',
        signTransaction: function(tx){...},
        sign: function(data){...},
        encrypt: function(password){...}
    }
```

Similarly, with ethers, you could use `ethers.Wallet.fromMnemonic` to add an account given it's seed phrase/mnemonic. More about it [here](https://docs.ethers.io/v5/api/signer/#Wallet).

Comment: Thanks and just a quick and silly question.....now will this new user would be able to do transactions from this imported account?  or  is this just added as a "watch-only" wallet?

Comment: @PriyanshuJain should be able to